# Speech_contexts phrase list not working in google speech.SpeechAsyncClient.streaming_recognize

Tags: asynchronous, google-cloud-platform, client, speech-to-text

Unable to make speech_contexts phrase lists work with speech.SpeechAsyncClient in Google Speech to Text..
The transcription works, but the phrase list appears to be ignored.
Is there any config that needs to be in-place?

When Using the speech.SpeechAsyncClient (version 2.17.2 in python) I created a phrase list :
speech_contexts {
phrases: "Burrito"
boost: 10.0
}
speech_contexts {
phrases: "burrito"
boost: 5.0
}
I expected the word audio for 'burrito' to be transcribed as 'Burrito' as text. However it continued to be 'burrito'.  Also I tried various phrase lists, but the recognition seems to ignore the phrase lists (same result with/without phrase list).
I verified that the proper speech_context is being sent in the 'streaming_config/Recogntionconfig like this:

```
    Recognitionconfig = speech.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding=speech.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
        #encoding = cloud_speech.ExplicitDecodingConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
        sample_rate_hertz=16000,
        language_code="en-US",
        model="latest_long",
        #enable_word_confidence=True,
        speech_contexts=speech_contexts #this contains the phrase list 
       
    )
    #The first message is the following streaming_config and is then followed by audio
    streaming_config = speech.StreamingRecognitionConfig(
            config=Recognitionconfig, interim_results=True
        )
```

Comment: May I know what documentation you are following for  this one?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [model adaptation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/adaptation) to strengthen the accuracy of your transcription results. It also uses [RecognitionConfig](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/RecognitionConfig) for the request body. Also follow this format when using [SpeechContext](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/RecognitionConfig#speechcontext).

```
{
  "phrases": [
    string
  ],
  "boost": number
}
```